# using STL Container set upper_bound

Tags: c++, stl, set

i have the following code which works perfect.

Objective: Given a number n, find the next and previous number of n.

Base on below example : if n = 50, then i will get 60 and 40 separately.

I am able to get 60 by using upper_bound. But how do i get a number before 50 i cant seem to find a provided algorithm to do that.

```
set<int> myset;
set<int>::iterator it,itlow,itup;

for (int i=1; i<10; i++) myset.insert(i*10); // 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
itup=myset.upper_bound (50);                 // 
cout << "upper_bound at position " << (*itup) << endl;
    //output: 60
```

With reference to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/lower_bound/, it says upper_bound "Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the container which **does not compare less than x**" but im sure there is something else that point to something that **compare less than x**.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
it = myset.lower_bound(50);
--it;
```

Of course, don't dereference that iterator unless you are sure there *is* an element less than 50 in the set.  You can check if `it == myset.begin()` for that.

Comment: What if 50 isn't present in the set?

Comment: now i feel so stupid. all i had to do is use "--itup;" 2 times to get to the lower range. thanks!

Comment: @AlanStokes it will still go to the upper or lower range as required. which is 60 and 40 respectively

Answer (score 1):

Use `lower_bound` like chris says see sgi: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/lower_bound.html and MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awxks70z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx.

`lower_bound` will return the position where insertion will occur such that the order is maintained which is what you want.

So

```
itlow = myset.lower_bound (50); // check if this is not pointing to myset.end()
--itlow; // should still check if this is in your container really
cout << "upper_bound at position " << (*itup) << "lower bound" << (*itlow) << endl;
```

better version I think

```
// check whether lower_bound returns myset.end() or myset.begin() for sensible and safe assignment
if (myset.lower_bound(50) != myset.end() && myset.lower_bound(50) != myset.begin())
{
  itlow = myset.lower_bound(50);
  --itlow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `lower_bound(49)`. Or possibly do `lower_bound(50)` and be prepared to go back one if needed.

Comment: Wouldn't it still return 50 on lower_bound(49)?

Comment: Gah, yes. It returns the first value >= the parameter. So yes, lower_bound(50) and back one *if there is a previous element* is the answer. These two always confuse me :-(